# Error when calling an Integral template member function with g++ and clang++

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, member, clang++

I'm currently stuck on a compilation error, which I can't really identify...

Here's a minimal working example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, int R>
class a_type
{
public:
     template <int N>
     double segment()
      {
           return 42;
      }
};

template <int M>
double func()
{
     a_type<double, M> a;
     return a.segment<1>();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     std::cout << func<10>() << std::endl;
     return 0;
}
```

The error message from GCC reads:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main
main.cpp: In function 'double func()':
main.cpp:18:26: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
      return a.segment<1>();
                          ^
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'double func() [with int M = 10]':
main.cpp:23:28:   required from here
main.cpp:18:22: error: invalid operands of types '<unresolved overloaded function type>' and 'int' to binary 'operator<'
      return a.segment<1>();
                  ^
```

Clang also says something similar:

```
clang++ main.cpp -o main
main.cpp:18:26: error: expected expression
     return a.segment<1>();
                         ^
```

So based on GCC's error message, 'a.segment' is a member function call missing the parentheses, which obviously gets rejected. But that does not make sense at all, since I don't see any reason for treating that expression as such. 
Moreover, if I change M to any integral number on line 17, like so:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, int R>
class a_type
{
public:
     template <int N>
     double segment()
      {
           return 42;
      }
};

template <int M>
double func()
{
     a_type<double, 58> a;
     return a.segment<1>();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     std::cout << func<10>() << std::endl;
     return 0;
}
```

then the code compiles and produces the expected result.

I would be very happy if somebody could enlighten me and show me what I am missing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know that `a.segment` is a template (it might depend on the value of `M`). So you have to tell it:

```
return a.template segment<1>();
```

In your second example it knows everything about the type of `a`, and so there is no problem.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! I had completely forgotten about that use of the template keyword. Guess my C++ was getting a little rusty ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler tells you that it has problems with

```
 a_type<double, M> a;
 return a.segment<1>();
```

because it cannot tell what members `a` can have, as it is a template (that might be specialized for some values of `M`).

> `main.cpp:18:22: error: invalid operands of types '<unresolved overloaded function type>' and 'int' to binary 'operator<'
>         return a.segment<1>();
>                     ^`

If `segment` is a template, it would be treated as `segment<1>`. If `segment` is a member variable of `a`, it should be compiled as `a.segment < 1`. How is the compiler to know?

You can fix this by using

```
return a.template segment<1>();
```